# How to extract all entries from a JSON array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

- Field name: `groups`
- Value:
  `[{"GroupId": "abcd-41234", "GroupName": "testingrule"}]`

How do to extract the `GroupID` and `GroupName` values as a separate fields using select statement?

These are my failed attempts:

```
select groups->>'GroupId' as id,
       groups->>'GroupName' as name`
from table_name
```

```
select (groups::json->>'GroupId')::json->>'id' as id
from table_name
```

```
select groups::json->>'GroupId' as id
from table_name`
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using the `jsonb` data type. If not, change your table definition.

If you want the values for all array elements for all rows in the table, you would use a lateral join like this:

```
SELECT exp.j ->> 'GroupId' AS groupid,
       exp.j ->> 'GroupName' AS groupname
FROM table_name AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.groups) AS exp(j);
```